# vHost config in cyberpanel

Tags: django, vps, host

I want to host my django website on cyberpanel vps.I have done all the things and uploaded project to file manager of website on cyberpanel.

here is my vHost config

```html
docRoot                   /home/fastrefer.online/public_html
vhDomain                  fastrefer.online
vhAliases                 www.fastrefer.online
adminEmails               jackgaming967@gmail.com
enableGzip                1
enableIpGeo               1

index  {
  useServer               0
  indexFiles              index.php, index.html
}

errorlog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.error_log {
  useServer               0
  logLevel                WARN
  rollingSize             10M
}

accesslog $VH_ROOT/logs/$VH_NAME.access_log {
  useServer               0
  logFormat               "%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-Agent}i""
  logHeaders              5
  rollingSize             10M
  keepDays                10  
  compressArchive         1
}

scripthandler  {
  add                     lsapi:fastr9279 php
}

extprocessor fastr9279 {
  type                    lsapi
  address                 UDS://tmp/lshttpd/fastr9279.sock
  maxConns                10
  env                     LSAPI_CHILDREN=10
  initTimeout             600
  retryTimeout            0
  persistConn             1
  pcKeepAliveTimeout      1
  respBuffer              0
  autoStart               1
  path                    /usr/local/lsws/lsphp81/bin/lsphp
  extUser                 fastr9279
  extGroup                fastr9279
  memSoftLimit            2047M
  memHardLimit            2047M
  procSoftLimit           400
  procHardLimit           500
}

phpIniOverride  {

}

module cache {
 storagePath /usr/local/lsws/cachedata/$VH_NAME
}

rewrite  {
 enable                  1
  autoLoadHtaccess        1
}

context / {
  type                    appserver
  location                /home/fastrefer.online/public_html/refer_and_earn
  binPath                 /usr/local/lsws/fcgi-bin/lswsgi
  appType                 wsgi
  startupFile             refer_and_earn/wsgi.py
  envType                 1
  env                     LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/bin/pyhton
  env                     PYTHONHOME=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/
}

context /.well-known/acme-challenge {
  location                /usr/local/lsws/Example/html/.well-known/acme-challenge
  allowBrowse             1

  rewrite  {

  }
  addDefaultCharset       off

  phpIniOverride  {

  }
}


vhssl  {
  keyFile                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/fastrefer.online/privkey.pem
  certFile                /etc/letsencrypt/live/fastrefer.online/fullchain.pem
  certChain               1
  sslProtocol             24
  enableECDHE             1
  renegProtection         1
  sslSessionCache         1
  enableSpdy              15
  enableStapling           1
  ocspRespMaxAge           86400
}
```

please let me know what i have to do to host my website properly.
i think, vHost config are not proper.
please let me know about the important fields i missed in here.

Comment: Did you follow https://community.cyberpanel.net/t/how-to-setup-django-application-on-cyberpanel-openlitespeed/30646/3 to setup? May I know the py version? Have you verified the code first, if you run manage.py runserver. will it work without cyberpanel?

Comment: i tested it using manage.py runserver, it works fine but cyberpanel litespeedserver don't return anything.
when i try to access it in the browser, it takes a lot of time and at the end it says error 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

I think the ENV value under the `context /` has some issue, please try to update it from

```
  env LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/bin/pyhton
  env PYTHONHOME=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/
```

to

```
  env LS_PYTHONBIN=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/bin/python
  env PYTHONPATH=/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/lib/python3.8:/home/fastrefer.online/public_html/refer_and_earn
```

Note, please substitute the `python3.8` to your current python version.